# How to get child views programmatically from a layout [from a R.layout resource]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

At some point in my app in need to get views (actually, it should be one) from a layout.
What I know about the layout is it's `int` reference, in the form of `R.layout.my_layout`.

How can I get the views inside?

I tried getting the root view with

`View rootView = (View) getResources().getLayout(R.layout.my_layout)`

but obviously it didn't work. `getLayout()` returns a `XMLResourceParser` object, which I don't know how to manage.

I can't work with IDs.

Comment: can't you just use findViewById?

Comment: @Blackbelt  not if the layout hasn't got an id...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use layout inflater

```
View rootView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_layout, null);
```

Comment: Accepted the first one, as all seem the same. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 4):

To load the view:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
```

And to get sub views from it:

```
    View sub = v.findViewById(R.id.your_sub_view_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout,null);
```

and get access to the childviews with

```
rootView.getChildAt(x);
```

or total amount of childs:

```
rootView.getChildCount();
```

Comment: What is `x` in getChildAt(x)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the layout resource ID, you need to inflate the layout and get the Views from that:

```
View rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutId, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the view, you just need to use -

```
view.findViewById(R.id.childID)
```

where,

childID is the child id of the parent view's child.